# Oblique projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I wanted to make a map of the world that shows all continents at once, Antarctica included, with as little distortion as possible on the continents and for that purpose, I noticed 2 opposite points on the earth (namely 30S 15W in the south Atlantic Ocean and 30N 165E, around 20 degrees off the coasts of Japan and Kamchatka) that could play the roles of north and south poles on my map so that most of the distortion happen in the oceans (south Atlantic and North Pacific).

After around one week of work with QGIS, I managed to make a somewhat satisfying map, that you can see details of here (don't pay attention to the top banner : it is an unrelated website that I own) :

https://vannier-editions.fr/le-monde-vu-autrement

It is an oblique Mercator projection, which is not exactly what I want, but I had to choose this for reasons I'll explain later. Here is the proj string used to create it :

```
+proj=omerc  +lat_2=0 +lon_2=75 +lat_1=-60 +lon_1=165
```

When you use this proj string, Argentina and Chile get split in two parts : the south side on the right, and the north side on the left. Thus, whenever I add a vector layer that crosses Argentina, I get tons of lines across the map which I tediously cut using the "split features" tool. Then, once my map was done, I edited the image with gimp and copy/pasted the left part of Argentina on the right and, since the projection is Mercator, they correspond.

However, this trick works only because I use Mercator, and I was lucky enough that only Argentina is split - in other projections I tried, the split is much worse and requires a lot of work.

I'd like to make a different projection (for example, an elliptical projection such as the Mollweide, but with a south pole at 20S 15W), to reduce the amount of distortion in Japan.
I won't be able to copy-paste a part of the map if I don't use a cylindrical projection. So I see two solutions to my problem :

- Is there a parameter of `proj +omerc` to make sure that Argentina doesn't get split in 2 parts (I'd prefer the split to occur between the southern tip of Chile and Antarctica). I tried to play with the lat_0 parameter, the false northing or easting parameters, but never got anything to work the way I want. I also tried other ways to use Oblique Mercator, but had the same problems :

  ```
  +proj=omerc +lat_0=75 +lonc=-15 +alpha=-65
  ```
- I think my problems would be solved if I could display some features twice. For example, I'd like to display the features of Argentina both in the left part of the map and the right part to avoid having lines across the map.

This is a picture of the results I usually get, with Argentina on the other side of the map.

[image: oblique Mercator]